# how to modify exe to make it console window hidden?

Tags: console, portable-executable

I have a program. The program had open a console window to display logs when it is started. I dont like this window, but no source code. So, how to hide this console? such as modify exe file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start it hidden.

I use this little VBScript code to do it. Create a `start hidden.vbs` file in the same folder of your `program.exe` and write this code in it:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "program.exe", 0
```

Run the `start hidden.vbs` and it should start the program hidden. The process will be only visible in the Task Manager.

Comment: Well you can crack the .exe to use the hidden flag on `CreateWindowEx` instead of using the one provided at run time. But I won't explain you how to do that.